# jQuery: execute a function AFTER toggleClass was executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, delay

I have

```
<script>
function myfunc(){
alert("show this alert in 5000ms after toggleClass executed")
//some code goes here
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mybtn').on('click',function(){
        $('#mydiv').toggleClass('newclass');
    });
 });
</script>
```

How to execute `myfunc()` in 5000ms after toggleClass was executed? Tried several ways but with no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

```
function myfunc() {
    alert("show this alert in 5000ms after toggleClass executed")
    //some code goes here
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mybtn').on('click', function () {
        $('#mydiv').toggleClass('newclass');
        setTimeout(myfunc, 5000)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
function myfunc(){
alert("show this alert in 5000ms after toggleClass executed");
//some code goes here
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mybtn').on('click',function(){
        $('#mydiv').toggleClass('newclass').delay(5000).queue(myfunc);        
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/lonewolfs/yasRz/)

Answer (score 1):

Use settimeout function

```
function myfunc() {
    alert("show this alert in 5000ms after toggleClass executed")
    //some code goes here
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mybtn').on('click', function () {
        $('#mydiv').toggleClass('newclass');
        setTimeout(myfunc, 5000)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a callback function like this

```
$('#mydiv').toggleClass('newclass', 5000).promise().done(function(){alert("done")});
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3BvHS/1/)

Comment: I suppose it was downvoted because it does not *directly* answer the question.

Comment: @Anar i'm not buying that unless the person who down voted..gives an explanation that its worthy to be down voted....

Comment: That wasn't me (just in case). I also would like to get an answer for the downvote before I accept the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the `$("#mydiv").toggleClass('newclass')` in a separate event.

For instance `<button class="mybtn" onmousedown="$('#mydiv').toggleClass('newclass')" onclick="myfunc();">Fast Toggle</button>`

If you toggle onmousedown the page will render with the toggle before the click event fires.